# Entity Framework : Include multiple childs level in a projection

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using a projection like this :

```
   Dim mylist = (From t In context.Myobj1 where t.id=6 _
         Select New With {_
         .Parent = t, _
        .fd = t.ch1.Where(Function(t3) t3.vl>5), _
        .fh = t.ch2 _
         }).ToList
```

The problem is that ch1 has a child collection "ch11" that I want to include in this projection.

Thank you !

---

**I make some test using the suggested solution below ,  and found the following problems :**

1) Sometimes the second levels childs are not loaded.But the strange is that this happen only in the case where where in the first level childs only one item is related with this second level child. ( fo example if in ch1 only one item is related with a specific item in ch11 , this item in ch11 is not loaded )

2) This solution only work ( of course with the problem described in 1) ) with second level childs. Doesn't work if try to apply the same logic with the third level or more.

Any solution ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You probably noticed that you can't use `Include` (as in `t.ch1.Include...`). So you have to add the child collection to your projection, e.g. by creating a nested anonymous type:

```
Dim mylist = (From t In context.Myobj1 where t.id=6 _
             Select New With {_
             .Parent = t, _
             .fd = From c1 in t.ch1.Where(Function(t3) t3.vl > 5) _
                   Select New With { _
                   c1 _
                   .c11 = c1.ch11 _
                   }, _
             .fh = t.ch2 _
             }).ToList
```

Now the `ch1`s will have their child collections `ch11`, because EF populates them by *relationship fixup*.

You can demonstrate that if you turn off lazy loading....

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
```

and then do...

```
myList.First().fd.First().c1.ch11
```

(*not* `myList.First().fd.First().c11`)

You'll see that the first `c1`'s `ch11` collection is returned without executing a new query. (With lazy loading enabled it would run a query, because `c1.ch11` is not marked as loaded when it is only populated by relationship fixup).

Comment: Thank you , it's working , but can this logic works with  other child levels like for example if ch11 has another child level ch111 .... ?

Comment: It's seems that is not working beyond the child level 2. any solution ?

Comment: You have to repeat this trick for each level you want to include.

Comment: I try to repeat but doesn't work , and I have other problem described in my edited first post